# Making adjustments to the potentiometers on a Electronmen EM - 285 DC - motor speed regulator

Tags: potentiometer

How to install and operate an Electromen EM - 285 DC (12/24V 20A) motor speed regulator made in Finland?

Having read through the leaflet that came with the unit and wired it up,  I find that there are three potentiometers located on the circuit board that need to have adjustments made to them. For anyone who is very knowledgeable of electronics, the terminology that is used in the leaflet would be very understandable. For someone like me who is very much an amateur hobbiest, it leaves me a little baffled.

I emailed the company's support team, but the reply basically repeated what was printed on the leaflet. That was from their head office in Finland.

The following was copied from the wiring and installation sheet.

1. A range trim, to scale the usable speed range.
   (This is all that it says on the leaflet, it does not tell you how to go about doing this.)
2. Current limit (l-lim ) limits the motor current, in other words the motor torque. Should this adjustment be used to set the limit to a suitable level according to the application? (It does not tell you how to.) I contacted the UK office. The reply it stated that there are no specific guidelines on setting the current limit - they suggest experimenting, until you find something that suits the application in question. “Suits the application in question” is a little vague, so it seems it is a case of hit and miss there.
3. Load compensation (RxI ) should be set to minimum in the beginning. Next set the motor RPM 20-30 %, and slowly increase compensation and simultaneously try loading the motor. If motor RPM is not affected by the loading the compensation adjustment is in optimum, but if the motor starts to twitch or running turns nervous, the adjustment is overcompensating. This has a lot more information on how to accomplish this, it seems that you make the adjustment on the compensation potentiometer when the motor is running, and then make the motor have to do some work, and the reaction from the motor, dictates the adjustments that need to be made. That's if I am correct in my understanding of what I am reading.

Can anyone with experience of making adjustments like the ones I have to make give me the benefit of their experience on how they went about it and put it in more understandable terms for someone with a basic knowledge of electronics?

Comment: Could you share what the application in question is, i.e. what mechanism the motor is driving, whether that mechanism cares more about exact speed, exact torque, something else, etc?

Comment: The speed regulator controls a 24V DC motor that is attached to a drive shaft, by a pulley, on this drive shaft is a flywheel, and then another pulley, a belt goes from this pulley, onto another pulley, on a single phase 230V Alternator. The rpm have to reach 3000 for the alternator to produce 230V AC. Sorry you lost me on the torque question, my knowledge does not cover torque, like I said, I am a very amateur hobbies

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Electromen EM - 285 documentation](https://electromen.com/files/6413/7811/0100/EN_EM-285.pdf) you should do the following:

1. Adjust the Ilim potentiometer to the maximum current rating of your motor. You have elsewhere stated that the motor is rated for 12A.
2. Adjust the range potentiometer to full speed (all the way clockwise.)
3. Adjust the compensation potentiometer to minimum (all the way counter clockwise.)
4. Adjust the potentiometer (knob) on the front of the control to 0 (full counter clockwise.)
5. Connect the motor (with its mechanical load) to the 24V power supply and adjust the knob so that the motor runs at the speed you need.  You say you need for the motor to run at 3000 RPM for the attached alternator to generate 230VAC, so turn up the knob until the alternator is putting out 230VAC.
6. Vary the mechanical load on the motor - the motor will change speed as the load varies.
7. Turn up the compensation potentiometer (turn clockwise) a little bit and vary the load.  The motor speed will change, but it should be less sensitive to load changes.
8. Repeat step 7 until turning the compensation potentiometer clockwise makes the motor more sensistive to load variations, then turn it back (counter clockwise) a little bit.

You say that the motor is turning an alternator.  You can vary the mechanical load on the motor by changing the electrical load on the alternator.  You could use electrical light bulbs as a load on the alternator.  No light bulbs = no load.  More light bulbs = more load.  Incandescent bulbs are probably best for this.

The range potentiometer is used to lower the maximum speed.  If you find that you can reach the required RPM with the front panel knob set in the lower 1/3 if its range, then you could turn the range potentiometer down (counter clockwise) so that the knob on the front can only push the speed to 1/3 of the maximum.  This allows finer control of the motor speed using the front panel knob.

---

You've mentioned elsewhere that the fuse you had inline with the motor melted.  The most likely cause was poor contact between the fuse holder and the fuse blades.  15A is a lot of current.  Poor contact will cause heating in the connection between the fuse and the holder.  You need a really good fuse holder and good fuses.

Since you are driving an alternator, you need to keep in mind that you will get less power out of the alternator than you put into the motor.

In an ideal world, you would get the same power out of the alternator as you put into the motor.  12A x 24V = 288 watts.  At 230VAC, you'd get about 1.2A.  There's electrical losses (eletrical resistance) in the windings of the motor and the alternator, and there's mechanical losses (friction) as well, so you will not be able to get the full 288 watts out of the alternator.  It would surprise me if you get as much as 150 watts out of the alternator.